# Internet stops working while playing online games

Tags: networking, internet

I am going through a strange problem. My internet connection stops working at random times while playing an online game(AOE2). No matter if I use a 3G donge or use my mobile phone tethering, it will stop working. Also I noticed in event viewer this event occurs everytime:

**The TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service entered the stopped state.**

> The TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service was successfully sent a stop control.
>
> The reason specified was: 0x40030011 [Operating System: Network Connectivity (Planned)]
>
> Comment: None

Also I am unable to ping 4.2.2.2 or 8.8.8.8 from my net connection. Is this normal?
What else I need to check?

Comment: Is this a laptop or a desktop? And when you use a 3G dongle or mobile phone tethering, how do you do it? Is the dongle connected by USB? Do you tether by USB? The problem is power saving gone awry. If all devices connect by USB, then you can solve it by turning off the Device Manager checkbox that allows the computer to disable the USB to save power.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your PC is suspending the USB ports after a while to save power. In the advanced power saving options in control panel there is an option to disable USB suspended setting. Disable this and this might fix your problem.

But another reason could be that 3G connections just arent meant for that type of online gaming. 3G is signal based often having a limit on download data and is usually only used for web browsing, sending emails and messages and perhaps playing some low spec turn based online games. But if I wanted to play AOE2 (great game btw) online I would never trust a 3G connection to sustain my game play.